# using php array that was created via $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I created a jQuery array of objects:

```
my_family = [
person {
 name = “nick”,
 age = 41,
 role = “dad”
},
person {
 name = “john”,
 age = 4,
 role = “son”
},
person {
 name = “sarah”,
 age = 31,
 role = “mom”
},
]
```

I am trying to post this to the same page via post as a php array, which I have done successfully :

```
$.post("http://www.samepage.com", {my_family: my_family});
```

I then want to use this data, but when I try to add it to a variable or manipulate it in any way the page is not responding. when I use the following code, I can see it in my firebug as printed into the html, but I can not add it to variables or anything, how come? this is what I use to see it in html:

```
print_r ($_POST['my_family']);
```

furthermore it doesnt print to the page with the name "my_family" but just "Array". My main goal is to loop though the array and store each "age" value into a new array. is what Im doing possible via the post method?

Comment: I updated print_r ($_POST['my_family']);, mistake when trying to simplify the question for this post

Comment: are those `“ ”` curly quotes really part of your code? if so, that will break your code. Use regular quotes `"var"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are POSTing some more complex data, you could try `JSON.stringify` that data, send it, and then decode it in PHP.

In JavaScript:

```
$.post("http://www.samepage.com", {my_family: JSON.stringify(my_family)});
```

In PHP:

```
$my_family = json_decode($_POST['my_family'], true);
print_r($my_family);

// And if you're storing 'age' values into a new array
$age_values = array();
foreach($my_family as $person) {
    array_push($age_values, $person['age']);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the PHP code because of some of my misunderstand of `json_decode`.

Comment: I think im having a problem with the first line of php, maybe my array is not compatible with the php array? here is what my array looks like after I post it with JSON.stringify:

[{\"final_user_id\":\"1\",\"final_name_id\":\"1\",\"final_nametype\":\"spanish\",\"final_price
\":\"33\",\"final_return\":\"1.8\"}]

Answer (score 1):

Here it appears that you are trying to read data as a POST which is not a form-posted, $_POST is a just a wrapper for data which is either  for

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded (content type for simple
  form-posts) OR
- multipart/form-data-encoded (for file uploads)

here basically you may want to read the JSON as raw input to php.
// in your php file..

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r ( $data);
```